# Webservice proxy loses authentication after a period of time

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, proxy, credentials

I have a web service that acts as a proxy to other web services.   In other words, it calls other web services and returns the results.   When it calls the other web services it passes the credentials and cookies passed to it from the browser to the other web services.

This works fine, however, after a period of time it starts to fail with authentication errors.  The only way to resolve them is to clear browser cache and restart the browser.  It seems like, though I can't prove it, that somehow the browser credentials are being expired on the network and they need to be refreshed in the browser.

Is there any way to force this refresh programmatically?